# Java: Copying an exe-file and launching afterwards fails

Tags: java, process, copy, windows-vista, launch

I want to copy an existing .exe-file from one directory to another and launch it afterwards with Java. Like this:

```
FileIO.copy( new File( sourceFile ), new File( targetFile ) );
System.out.println( "Existing: " + new File( targetFile ).exists() );
System.out.println( "Launching " + targetFile );
String cmd[] = { targetFile };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
p.waitFor();
System.out.println( "Result: " + p.exitValue() );
```

The output is like this:

```
Existing: true
Launching C:\test\Launcher.new.exe
Result: 2
```

So Java says that the file is valid and existing, but Windows just can't launch the process because it thinks the file is not there. The pathes are absolute and with backslashes. I also have all permissions on the files so I'm allowed to execute them.
The Launcher.new.exe is generated by Launch4j, so it's more or less standalone. At least it doesn't depend on DLLs in the same folder. But strange: It works when I copy and launch the notepad.exe.

One more strange thing: If I don't copy the file by Java but by hand, the launching also fails with the same error.

OS is Vista with SP1.

Any clue?

Comment: ProcessMonitor shows no error and claims, that the file was launched. But nothing happened there afterwards as well.

Comment: What kind of process is it that you trying to launch? You may be falling foul to the UAC in Vista.

Comment: It's an .exe developed by me. No UAC pops up.
Also there is no "Security-software" with sandbox-like stuff.

Comment: Updated my answer, maybe there's something helpful there, please take a look!

Comment: So when you run the file yourself it fails with error 2 - sounds like the code has `System.exit(2);` somewhere and launching with no arguments causes that condition ...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I wonder if this might be Vista's wonderful User Access Controls at play...

Are you working within Program Files? If so, move everything out into a seperate folder (c:\CopyTest) and try again - see if that helps...

Comment: I'm already testing from the folder "C:\test".
I'm suspecting some kind of freaky virtualization too, but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: Any way you can run as Adminstrator to rule out any Vista silliness?

Answer (score 0):

If your path contains forward slashes, you might want to try changing them to backslashes before `exec`ing. Also, you should try to make the path absolute, including a drive letter and colon (e.g. `C:\test\myprog.exe`). Note that if you code the path in a Java String, you need to double up the backslashes...

Once you get that working, you can ease up on those constraints until you figure out what broke your attempt.

---

EDIT 1: Some common pitfalls with `exec()` are mentioned in [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). I don't think any of these apply, but you may want to use the coding from the last example to run your .EXE within `CMD.EXE` to get decent path resolution, error handling and such.

---

EDIT 2: Your executable file name needs to be interpreted as a long file name. I'm not positive the API can/will handle this. Please try giving the .EXE a short, simple name (just for testing) like NEWPROG.EXE (with no second dot in the name, either!) But first definitely give it a try with CMD.EXE first.

---

EDIT 3: From reading comments to the other answer: Is it possible your program is indeed running, and itself returning a status of 2 because *it* is failing to find a file? Is there some way to verify operation of your program, perhaps by calling it from a `.CMD` batch script that you run from your Java program, and having it write output redirected to a file?

Comment: The pathes are absolute and with backslashes. Forgot to mention that. :)

Comment: Added the actual path and filename now.

Comment: Back/forward slashes doesn't matter in Windows.

Comment: @BalusC: You don't usually make completely incorrect statements. Maybe you meant that back/forward slashes don't matter in Java? That granted, the command is passed as an array of `tokens of a command line` (so says the doc) and therefore probably subject to Windows' syntax constraints. I believe forward slashes would have been a very valid cause for Status 2.

Comment: Try yourself in command console. `cd c:/program files` and so on.

Comment: I did exactly that, of course. In the console in Windows 7, I get a "file not found" if I try to execute a program with a path using forward slashes. I've never encountered a Windows where this wasn't the case, so I'd be interested to hear where you have this working.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, it's hard to give specific answer.  Check your permissions on the c:\test directory and the permissions on target file you are trying to execute.

Comment: I'd love to add more details, what's missing?
Replaced the placeholder with the actual path and filename.

Comment: Does the exe depend on dlls? Are these in the same folder?

Comment: The exe is standalone, more or less. It's generated by Launch4j.

Comment: As a debugging aid, try copying and launching "notepad.exe". This will then tell you if it is a general problem with all exes or a specific problem with your generated exe.

Comment: Nice idea, I tried it. And it works with the notepad.exe. Strange.

Comment: What happens if you open a console and run c:\test\launch.new.exe? It's quite likely that depends upon some dlls, so you need to check if your PATH variable is correct. My guess is that this is a problem loading one of the EXEs dependency dlls.

Comment: If you change your command args array to "cmd.exe","/c","c:\test\launch.new.exe". This emulates what the console is doing.

Comment: Please confirm that you're running your java class as the same user as when you open a console. Also try not copying the file in java, but copy it by hand to your target directory, and try launching that from java. Is FileIO from the apache commons project? Curious if the target file is being closed.

Comment: Same user: Confirmed.
FileIO is a utility-class written by us. The files are closed.
Copying by hand and not by Java: Just tried and it has the same effect, exitcode == 2. Now things really are getting strange. :/

Comment: Thanks for the test results. One more thing to try - can you launch the source exe instead, see if that works? i.e. change String[] cmd = { sourceFile }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem you might me facing is not having the bundled more in the directory. Launch4j may convert your program to exe, but there just be a local directory to the jre. That folder contains the bin and lib files of any existing Java jre.
Maybe it helps...

**Update**
Seems like some people are having a tough time understanding what I said. No problem, I'll explain.

Let's take an example that I have created a simple Client Chat App in Java and I exported it into a runnable `.../ClientChatApp.jar` file. Yet, it still doesn't have the dependencies within it to run the file and needs the installation of Java in the desktop for doing so. For example here, `.../ClientChatApp.jar` still needs the dependencies of `javax.swing.*`, `java.net.*` and `java.io.*`. Hence it will locate those dependencies from the JDK/JRE it is supposed to use.

Now, when it comes to converting from `.../ClientChatApp.jar` to `.../ClientChatApp.exe`, it will work as expected, only if the desktop has Java installed, so that it can collect the dependencies from there. This is not user friendly since any user who doesn't have Java installed will have to install it first to be able to use your app.

Here's where Launch4j helps. When you are converting from jar to exe using this program, then it helps to redirect where the exe will look for the dependencies in a local folder, usually being `.../jre/...` in the sam directory as the `.../ClientChatApp.exe` file. Quick tip: To actually do that, go to the same directory as where you want to have the exe file, create a folder there called `jre`. Now go to `C:/Program Files/Java/<<your JDK or JRE folder>>/` and then select and copy the `bin` and `lib` folders and copy them. Then go to the directory where you created the folder of `jre` and paste both of the folders in the folder.

Many users may have already done it, but why I explained all the above is to give a clear understanding of what the `jre` folder does and hence come to the main point, that you will have to also send the jre folder with the exe file to the user, otherwise there is a point of failure while execution.
You can send them into a .zip file or create an installer exe using Inno Setup. I recommend doing more research if you're wanting to use Inno Setup.

That's it. Thank You! (plz upvote me, its my first answer)

Comment: not sure what "the bundled more in the directory" means.  Please update your answer to clearly explain what your solution is for the OP (remember this is a problem from nearly 11 years ago).